# Can hemophilia be advantageous when the blood circulation is stopped?

Tags: brain, blood-circulation, brain-damage

First of all, I'm a computer engineer and I have nothing to do with Medical Sciences so this question might sound ridiculous.

I found a book(
*Hall, J. E. 1. (2016). Guyton and Hall textbook of medical physiology (13th edition)*, page 282) and started reading some of the pages randomly. I saw a paragraph about *"What happens in the brain when blood circulation is stopped"*.

It was saying that; many experiments show that the damage is done by *blood coagulation* in the brain and if that coagulation is prevented the damage will mostly be prevented.

The exact paragraph:

> **Effect of Circulatory Arrest on the Brain**

> A special problem in
> circulatory arrest is to prevent detrimental effects in the brain as
> a result of the arrest. In general, more than 5 to 8 minutes of
> total circulatory arrest can cause at least some degree of permanent
> brain damage in more than half of patients. Circulatory arrest for
> as long as 10 to 15 minutes almost always permanently destroys
> significant amounts of mental power.

> **For many years, it was taught
> that this detrimental effect on the brain was caused by the acute
> cerebral hypoxia that occurs during circulatory arrest. However,
> experiments have shown that if blood clots are prevented from
> occurring in the blood vessels of the brain, this will also prevent
> much of the early deterioration of the brain during circulatory
> arrest.** For instance, in animal experiments, all the blood was
> removed from the animal’s blood vessels at the beginning of
> circulatory arrest and then replaced at the end of circulatory arrest
> so that no intra- vascular blood clotting could occur. In this
> experiment, the brain was usually able to withstand up to 30 minutes
> of circulatory arrest without permanent brain damage. Also,
> administration of heparin or streptokinase (to pre- vent blood
> coagulation) before a cardiac arrest was shown to increase the
> survivability of the brain up to two to four times longer than usual.

> It is likely that the severe brain damage that occurs from circulatory
> arrest is caused mainly by permanent blockage of many small blood
> vessels by blood clots, thus leading to prolonged ischemia and
> eventual death of the neurons.

So the question is:

If I have hemophilia, in this situation, is this an advantage for me?

Comment: What book? What pages? it's difficult to respond to "I read something somewhere" questions because I'm pretty sure you misinterpreted what you read. Stopping blood flow to the brain is immediately harmful and fatal within minutes regardless of coagulation.

Comment: @CareyGregory updated, there is no misinterpretation.

Comment: Thanks, interesting find.